# Embed Batch Script file and run in C++ Console Project

Tags: c++, batch-file, cmd, console, embed

I will Embed batch file in resouce project , and i want run batch script in console.

how to run embed script

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
#define WINDOWS_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>

std::wstring GetEnvString()
{
    wchar_t* env = GetEnvironmentStrings();
    if (!env)
        abort();
    const wchar_t* var = env;
    size_t totallen = 0;
    size_t len;
    while ((len = wcslen(var)) > 0)
    {
        totallen += len + 1;
        var += len + 1;
    }
    std::wstring result(env, totallen);
    FreeEnvironmentStrings(env);
    return result;
}

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

     std::wstring env = GetEnvString();
    env += L"myvar=boo";
    env.push_back('\0'); // somewhat awkward way to embed a null-terminator

    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(STARTUPINFO) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    wchar_t cmdline[] = L"cmd.exe /C f.bat";

    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, cmdline, NULL, NULL, false, CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,
        (LPVOID)env.c_str(), NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        std::cout << GetLastError();
        abort();
    }

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

    getch();
}
```

[embed batch script file in c++ console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ASSA.jpg)

this is location batch file i want run from resource project

```
 wchar_t cmdline[] = L"cmd.exe /C f.bat";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [std::system](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream fl("test.bat");
    fl << "@echo off\n"
          "echo testing batch.\n"
          "cd c:\\windows\n"
          "dir";
    fl.close();
    system("test.bat");
}
```

With system however you can simply execute commands, you cannot get their output. To get output, you may redirect output from your .bat to a file, or you may use [popen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and you can read output like regular file. Note that popen gets you stdout only, but you may redirect stderr to stdout:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    FILE *p = _popen("missing_executable.exe 2>&1", "r");
    if (p)
    {
        char data[1024];
        int n = 0;
        while (fgets(data, 1024, p))
            printf("%02d: %s", ++n, data);
        int ret = _pclose(p);
        printf("process return: %d\n", ret);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("failed to popen\n");
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
01: 'missing_executable.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
02: operable program or batch file.
process return: 1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

If you want to store your .bat file as a resource in windows executable you could use [FindResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042(v=vs.85).aspx)/[LoadResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046(v=vs.85).aspx)/[LockResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648047(v=vs.85).aspx) to get actual bat file from your executable. Something like this:

```
HMODULE module = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
// update with your RESOURCE_ID and RESOURCE_TYPE.
HRSRC res = FindResource(module, MAKEINTRESOURCE(RESOURCE_ID), RESOURCE_TYPE);
HGLOBAL resMem = LoadResource(module, res);
DWORD resSize = SizeofResource(module, res);
LPVOID resPtr = LockResource(resMem);

char *bytes = new char[resSize];
memcpy(bytes, resPtr, resSize);
```

Now you can save bytes to a file and execute it using [std::system](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) or [popen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: you would need to get the embedded resource and save it to a file anyways (to some temp location), and then execute that bat file using system or popen. Or if you don't want to use temporary file, you'd need to read data from your resource and create some `cmd /c param1 param2 ...` string that can be executed using system.

Comment: @JavadRajabzade check updated answer for sample code to load windows resource with `FindResource/LoadResource/LockResource `